# Table td adjust to its contents

Tags: html, css, html-table

Curious if there is a way to get a table  to adjust to its contents.
My idea was to have four tds. The first three with content. The last would simply fill up the rest of the unused space.

```
<tr>
   <td>Content</td>
    <td>More Content</td>
    <td>The Most Content</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This, however, just gave the tds seemingly random widths. I haven't done much work with tables, and am pretty sure i'm missing something obvious.

Ideally i'm looking for something that acts similar to display:inline-block. How it adjusts the object's size in relation the content inside of it.

Comment: can you post your CSS?

Comment: This is kind of strange because tables behavior  is exactly as you are describing.The table cells stretch depending on the cell's content. If you have more than one row, the cells on a given column will resize to the cell in the same column that have more content. Maybe there is something in your stylesheet that is keeping the cells to resize. Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fMTc5/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what may have been causing it, but `display: inline-table` gave me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your first three table cells a width of 1%, it will definitely be no bigger than the content and will probably behave as you're expecting.